# How to validate images on iOS have not been tampered/shopped after capturing them

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an app for iPhone that will let users capture video/pics and captures their geo info and uploads them to a database online.

I am primarily trying to certify the images weren't manipulated/shopped and are same copy as initial shot.

Is there any unique image data on iOS that I can use to validate images?

Comment: Generate a SHA1024 of the image when they are captured/uploaded.

Comment: @ryantxr that would only work if the images were captured inside OP's app

Comment: Your app is capturing, so what's the issue? Just send them to the server after capture and don't allow users to select from their media library.

Comment: @meaning-matters I don't think that solution is complete. What if there is no internet connectivity immediately after image capture ? User can probably access the image and modify it in meantime using another app.

Answer (score 0):

- Hard requirement: Your app needs to capture, because any other app could apply changes before saving to iOS image library.
- Save image to the local storage of your app, not to the iOS image library.
- Or, if you do want to use the iOS image library, you need to keep track of all images that were captured in your app. Create some hash (MD5, SHA, ... whatever) of each image after it's been freshly captured. Store the list of hashes on disk (in `NSUserDefault`, in a file, or in a CoreData database, whatever you wish). When a user selects an image, generate its has and check if you can find it in the list. In case you allow upload only once, delete the hash from the list after upload.
- You could also look at comparing creation date and modification date of an image file that comes from the iOS image library. Both timestamps must be the same.